# Matlab replace the nan with average of previous and next non-missing value

Tags: matlab, nan

all,
I have a large dataset with a lot of continuous NAs, is there any fast way to replace the NAs with the average of previous and next non-missing value by column?
Thanks a lot
Lou

Comment: What do you mean "by column"? Is it a 2D array?

Comment: What if the NaN is first or last in the column? You should edit the question to include a minimal example with expected output

Comment: what if NaNs are consecutive in any column?

Comment: There is no NA in the first and last row and it is 2D array. Luis give the exact answers I need, thanks so much.

Comment: Parag's method works for my dataset too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming NaNs are not in the first/last row in any column, here is how I would do it:

(If there are multiple consecutive NaNs, it searches for previous ann next non-missing values and averages them).

```
% Creating A

A=magic(7);
newA=A;  %Result will be in newA
A(3,4)=NaN;
A(2,1)=NaN;
A(5,6)=NaN;
A(6,6)=NaN;
A(4,6)=NaN;

% Finding NaN position and calculating positions where we have to average numbers
ind=find(isnan(A));
otherInd=setdiff(1:numel(A(:)),ind);
for i=1:size(ind,1)
   temp=otherInd(otherInd<ind(i));
   prevInd(i,1)=temp(end);
   temp=otherInd(otherInd>ind(i));
   nextInd(i,1)=temp(1);
end

% For faster processing purposes

allInd(1:2:2*length(prevInd))=prevInd;
allInd(2:2:2*length(prevInd))=nextInd;
fun=@(block_struct) mean(block_struct.data)
prevNextNums=A(allInd);
A
newA(ind)=blockproc(prevNextNums,[1 2],fun)

%-----------------------Answer--------------------------
A =

30    39    48     1    10    19    28
NaN    47     7     9    18    27    29
46     6     8   NaN    26    35    37
 5    14    16    25    34   NaN    45
13    15    24    33    42   NaN     4
21    23    32    41    43   NaN    12
22    31    40    49     2    11    20

newA =

30    39    48     1    10    19    28
38    47     7     9    18    27    29
46     6     8    17    26    35    37
 5    14    16    25    34    23    45
13    15    24    33    42    23     4
21    23    32    41    43    23    12
22    31    40    49     2    11    20
```

Comment: This seems to fail when there are consecutive `NaN`s in a given column. For example, try with `A(6,6)=NaN` also

Comment: Please read the first line. "Assuming NaNs are not in the first/last row in any column, and two NaNs are not consecutive in any column". For that matter, any method will fail since the behavior is not defined by the OP.

Comment: Ah, ok. But then the OP said "a large dataset with _a lot of continuous NAs_". Sorry but I can't upvote :-)

Comment: Haha, that's not a concern. Actually, I had asked the OP the same question about consecutive NaNs, but this problem was too interesting for me to wait :).

Comment: Oh, I guess he means, if there are continuous NaNs then we have to search for previous or next non-missing value.

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood, and that's what my answer does (see my example). The behaviour is undefined for `NaN`'s in first or last position, though

Comment: @LuisMendo I took care of consecutive NaNs, this is the best I could come up with :).

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question... if only you explained clearly what you want. Maybe it's this?

```
data = [1 3 NaN 7 6 NaN NaN 2].'; %'// example data: column vector
isn = isnan(data); %// determine which values are NaN
inum = find(~isn); %// indices of numbers
inan = find(isn); %// indices of NaNs
comp = bsxfun(@lt,inan.',inum); %'// for each (number,NaN): 1 if NaN precedes num
[~, upper] = max(comp); %// next number to each NaN (max finds *first* maximum)
data(isn) = (data(inum(upper))+data(inum(upper-1)))/2; %// fill with average
```

In this example: original data:

```
>> data.'
ans =
     1     3   NaN     7     6   NaN   NaN     2
```

Result:

```
>> data.'
ans =
     1     3     5     7     6     4     4     2
```

If you have a 2D array and want to work by columns, a `for` loop over columns is probably the best option.

And of course, if there can be `NaN`'s at the beginning or end of a column, the problem is undefined.

Comment: I don't think a `for` loop over a 2-D array is needed. See my answer.